# New member registration set to require activation, but new registrants are working without it

Tags: members, freemember, registration, register, activation

I'm using [Freemember](https://github.com/expressodev/freemember/blob/master/docs/register_tag.md) plugin to manage member forms. I just setup a registration form and tried both activation methods, "self activation via email" and "manual activation by administrator". But a registrant can log in immediately and they never appear under "pending members" in the CP. Any ideas why they are being activated immediately? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I had to remove the group_id="7" from the freemember registration form tag. With it in there, the registrants never went to "Pending" first, they would be put into the member group with id of 7.